# Subsequence Search

Tags: searching, parsing, xml

I need to parse some xml code. I need to extract some values withing pattern elements. I made an example of my trouble.
Here is some complicated xml list:

```
list = {p[1, c, a, p[1, 2], q, b, b, a, p[3, 4], q, b, c, d, a, p[5, 6], q, b, {}, p[7, 8]]};
```

I need to extract this:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

I tried to use this pattern:

```
In[494]:= Cases[list,  p[__, a, p[x_, y_], q, __] :> {x, y}, Infinity]
Out[494]= {{1, 2}}
```

It doesn't work as I hope. (

I tried some other variants with ReplaceList, SequencePosition, but seems like I can't use it properly.

Mathematica 11.0
TQ

For solution TQ to **Jason B.** & **m_goldberg**
First of all, I understand that I need to extract most inner list with desired patterns. And then **SequenceCases** works well. Solution with **Partition** also works good.

I've compicated the example to show working solutions:

```
In[614]:=list = {p[1, c, a, p[1, 2], q, b, b, a, p[3, 4], q, b, c, d, a, p[5, 6], q, b, {}, p[7, 8], e, a, p[2], q, e]};
         First@Cases[list, p[args : PatternSequence[___, a, _p, q, ___]]:>SequenceCases[{args}, {a, p[x_, y_], q} :> {x, y}], Infinity]
         Cases[Partition[List @@ list[[1]], 3, 1], {a, p[x_, y_], q} -> {x, y}]

Out[615]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
Out[616]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how extensible this is, but it works for your case,

```
Cases[list,
    p[args:PatternSequence[___, a, _p, q, ___]] :> SequenceCases[
        {args},
        {a, p[x_, y_], q} :> {x, y}
    ],
    Infinity
]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works for your list, but like Jason B, I don't that is will be applicable to your XML problem.

```
Cases[Partition[List @@ list[[1]], 3, 1], {a, u : p[_, _], q} -> u]
```

> `{p[1, 2], p[3, 4], p[5, 6]}`

Comment: My guess is it's like an `XMLElement` type case...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cases[list, p[pat : Longest[PatternSequence[___, a, p[_,_], q]], ___] :> 
    Cases[{pat}, p[x__] :> {x}, All], All]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}}

Comment: It doesn't work properly:
list = {p[1, c, a, p[1, 2], q, b, b, a, p[3, 4], q, b, c, d, a, p[5, 6], q, b, {}, p[7, 8], e, a, p[2], q, e]};
Cases[list, p[pat : Longest[PatternSequence[___, a, _p, q]], ___] :> 
  Cases[{pat}, p[x__] :> {x}, All], All]
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {2}}}

Comment: @VasilySH, try the updated version (using `p[_,_]` instead of `_p` inside `PatternSequence[...]`).